# NSTableView and drag and drop from Finder

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, finder

I'm trying to implement drag and drop from the Finder into an NSTableView of my app. The setup uses an `NSTableView`, an array controller which acts as a datasource using Cocoa bindings to a Core Data store.

I did the following, basically following various blog posts I found on SO and other sites:

In the `awakeFromNib` of my view controller I call:

```
[[self sourcesTableView] registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSPasteboardTypePNG, nil]];
```

I subclassed NSArrayController and added the following methods to my subclass (the reasoning for subclassing is that the array controller needs to be informed of the drop as it acts as the datasource of the table view):

```
- (BOOL) tableView: (NSTableView *) aTableView acceptDrop: (id < NSDraggingInfo >) info row: (NSInteger) row dropOperation: (NSTableViewDropOperation)operation
```

My implementation for the above currently only writes to the log and then returns a boolean YES.

```
- (NSDragOperation) tableView: (NSTableView *) aTableView validateDrop: (id < NSDraggingInfo >) info proposedRow: (NSInteger) row proposedDropOperation: (NSTableViewDropOperation) operation
```

In IB I have the array controller pointing to my custom NSArrayController subclass.

Result: nothing. When I drag a PNG from the desktop onto my table view, nothing happens and the file happily bounces back to its origin. I must be doing something wrong but don't understand what. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A drag from the Finder is always a file drag, not an image drag. You'll need to support the dragging of URLs from the Finder.

To do that, you need to declare that you want URL types:

```
[[self sourcesTableView] registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeFileURL]];
```

You can validate the files like so:

```
 - (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView validateDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)operation
{
    //get the file URLs from the pasteboard
    NSPasteboard* pb = info.draggingPasteboard;

    //list the file type UTIs we want to accept
    NSArray* acceptedTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];

    NSArray* urls = [pb readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL class]]
     options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey,
                acceptedTypes, NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey,
                nil]];

    //only allow drag if there is exactly one file
    if(urls.count != 1)
        return NSDragOperationNone;

    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}
```

You'll then need to extract the URL again when the `tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:` method is called, create an image from the URL and then do something with that image.

Even though you are using Cocoa bindings, you still need to assign and implement an object as the `datasource` of your `NSTableView` if you want to use the dragging methods. Subclassing `NSTableView` will do no good because the datasource methods are not implemented in `NSTableView`.

You only need to implement the dragging-related methods in your datasource object, not the ones that provide table data as you're using bindings to do that. It's your responsibility to notify the array controller of the result of the drop, either by calling one of the `NSArrayController` methods such as `insertObject:atArrangedObjectIndex:` or by modifying the backing array using Key-Value Coding-compliant accessor methods.

Comment: Thanks, but the table view still does not accept any drag/drops. Any file I drag from the Finder bounces back.... I do use  Cocoa bindings to attach the table to its data source.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You still need to implement a datasource object.