# Dragging URLs into my app

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308008/nstableview-and-drag-and-drop-from-finder) about dragging content from OS X Finder into an `NSTableView`. This all works nicely now. However, if I want to drag URLs from a browser address bar into my app, I first need to drag them to the desktop (where they appear as a .webloc file) and then drag them into my app.

Is there a way to directly drag them from the browser address bar into my app, without having to drag them to the desktop first?

I tried registering `kUTTypeURL` but this doesn't seem to work as dragged URLs bounce back to their origin:

```
[[self sourcesTableView] registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: (NSString*)kUTTypeFileURL, (NSString*)kUTTypeURL, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [my accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10309544/50122) to your other question, the code I provided specifically restricts the URLs that your app can accept to file URLs:

```
NSArray* urls = [pb readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL class]]
 options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] 
                                     forKey: NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey]];
```

Note the options dictionary containing a boolean `YES` for the `NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey`.

If you want to accept any URL, just do this:

```
NSArray* urls = [pb readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL class]]
                                  options:nil];
```

Or even better, you can require that you'll accept any URL as long as it is of a particular type, in this case an image:

```
NSArray* acceptedTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
NSArray* urls = [pb readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL class]]
                                  options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:acceptedTypes 
                                   forKey:NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey]];
```

Comment: Fair point. I was not paying attention to the pasteboard side of the drag operation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That's fine. I've simplified the answer on your original question to use the `NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey`, which I wasn't aware of myself until today, so we both learned something :-)