# On Mac, Drag file to my NSTableVIew?

Tags: macos, swift, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I would like be able to drag (any) file to my view-based NSTableView, so in the delegate I have this setup:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSDraggingDestination
{
    @IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView! // connected in storyboard.

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerForDraggedTypes([NSFilenamesPboardType])
        // …
    }

    func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation
    {
        println("Drag entered.")
        return .Copy
    }

    func prepareForDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

    func draggingUpdated(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation
    {
        return .Copy
    }
    // ...
}
```

But my program just refuses to react to a drag-n-drop.  When I drag a file from Finder to it and release, the file icon just flies back to Finder.  Am I missing something in my code?

UPDATE: I added this

```
func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

but it still doesn’t work.  Should I implement this in my view instead of the delegate?  The document says “Either a window object or its delegate may implement these methods;”

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29233824/2227743).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answer:

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10308008/782130), and realized that there are methods that need implement in the datasource sector also; namely [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004178-RH2-SW9).  And the drag-n-drop works now.

Comment: Can you post your final solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sample code Apple puts in their ["Receiving Drag Operations" documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/acceptingdrags.html), the last function they put there is an implementation of:

[`- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingDestination_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSDraggingDestination/performDragOperation:)

You need to implement that and return "`YES`" to indicate the drag succeeded.

Comment: Thank you.  I added that and it still doesn’t work.  Please see my update in the question.